# Get function for searching is not giving the search result but returning all the elements while unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, nunit, web-api-testing

I have a function called GetAuthors which takes an expression for checking if given string is in authors names. I have problems while unit testing. The function supposed to find names that contains the given string but I realized it always returns everything in the list. I tested with G letter it supposed to fail but it passes. I have only found examples with no parameters for get functions unit testing. I am new to unit testing in web api. I share the code below.

Test function:

```
[Test]
    public async Task AuthorHandler_GetAuthors_ReturnsAuthors()
    {
        var handler = new GetAuthorsHandler(_authorRepositoryMock.Object, _mapper);
        var authors = new List<Author> { 
            new Author{Id = 2, Name = "Orhan", Surname = "Pamuk"},
            new Author{Id = 3, Name = "Patti", Surname = "Smith"},
            new Author{Id = 1, Name = "J.R.R.", Surname = "Tolkien"}

        };
        
        string str = "G";
        str=str.Trim().ToUpper();
        _authorRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetAuthors(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Author, bool>>>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(authors);

        //Act
        var result = await handler.Handle(new GetAuthorsQuery(str), CancellationToken.None);
        
        //Assert
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, result.Count());

    }
```

GetAuthors function in repository:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Author>> GetAuthors(Expression<Func<Author, bool>> pred = null)
    {
        if (pred == null) return await _context.Authors.Include(a => a.Book).ToListAsync();
        else return await _context.Authors.Where(pred).Include(b => b.Book).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Handler:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<AuthorDto>> Handle(GetAuthorsQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<Author> authors;
        if (request.Str != null)
        {
            request.Str = request.Str.Trim().ToUpper();
            authors = await _authorRepository.GetAuthors(x => x.Name.Trim().ToUpper().Contains(request.Str));
        }
        else { authors = await _authorRepository.GetAuthors(null); }
        
        if (authors == null) return null;
        return _mapper.Map<List<AuthorDto>>(authors);
    }
```

Comment: That should come as no surprise. You tell your mock to return the full list no matter what the input is.

Comment: Your method you want to test seems to be Handle. You don't test GetAuthors here and GetAuthors does the filtering. So the correct filtering is part of your testsetup not part of the method under test.

Comment: @PalleDue I thought about that too but I couldn't find how to return exactly the result of that search.

Comment: You need to mock correctly. If you want a specific return then write the mock accordingly. Getting the exact return means letting the mock return the exact result.

Comment: @Ralf I understand but in the Setup part I set up GetAuthors function and call the function via handler.

Comment: How do I return the result of the function inside the setup? For example if I give O it will only return the first element of the list. And If I put this into ResultsAsync manually, it's not like testing. It sounds like I am just showing what I want to see.

Comment: It does not matter. You test Handle and for Handle it does not matter what GetAuthor does or how and if it actually correct that up to the tests of that method. Here for Handle it only matters how this method deals with the dependency. Is GetAuthor called with the expected input. Does Handle handle the return correctly. Can it deal with a result from GetAuthor, without a result or with Exception coming from that method. But not that the result of GetAuthor is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    _authorRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetAuthors(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Author, bool>>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(authors);
```

This line means, that whenever you ask for `_authorRepository.GetAuthors(predicate);`, you will always get the same result -> `authors`. You are not testing filtering, because you've mocked it entirely.

You can mock the repository to use the predicate on `authors` list, like so:

```
_authorRepositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetAuthors(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Author, bool>>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Author, bool>> predicate) => authors.Where(predicate));
```

Mocks can not only return hardcoded data, but can also perform some logic, or return delegate functions.

Comment: Thank you so much @KifoPL . It worked and I understand the logic now.